# ldd finds a libQtCore magically

Tags: c++, qt, unix

when I LDD my program, i get this line among others

```
libQtCore.so.4 => /Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/lib/libQtCore.so.4
```

however this path is neither in my PATH nor in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH and executing:

```
set | grep -i qt
```

I find that the "bin" repository only is in my path

```
/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/bin/
```

But there is no any environment variable set to the path of the QtCore libraries.

**Question: how does the "ldd" command find this path ? ( the program also executes fine )**

Comment: Something in the makefile?

Comment: well nothing special in the make file -L/path/to/libs -lQtCore

Comment: you mean that from the makefile, there could be something in the executable which would indicate to the ldd command the absolute path to a dependency ? This is very dangerous , as it is not protable at all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ldd actually executes your program using load tracing. The loader (ld.so or ld-linux.so) uses a cache created by running ldconfig after one or more .so files are installed in a directory. You can find the relevant information [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).
There are a few methods to override this if you want to use a different Qt installation. The easiest one, is to set

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<my Qt libs location>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

in a script and then run a shell like

```
bash --posix  # avoid changing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH again by sourcing configuration file
```

This will run your program only with your selected Qt installation without affecting other programs installed in your system.
If you don't care about that, then you can add this in your shell profile or bashrc, etc., depending on what shell you use.

One more thing: if your program loads via links, i.e. libQtCore.so or libQtCore.so.5, etc, then you'll need to create those links too in the "my Qt libs location", if they are not already there.

Hope this helps.